# How can I get Google Tag Manager to execute python and Django code?

Tags: python, django, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to replace Google Analytics (GA) code with Google Tag Manager (GTM) code. The code is meant to identify users with a username in our system.

In my current GA code I call a file through Django:

```
    {{ google_analytics }}
```

That pulls up this code:

```
    def google_analytics(request):
disabled = {"google_analytics": ""}

# don't track internal users
if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated:
    if request.user.email and request.user.email.lower().endswith('@trellis.law'):
        return disabled

    if request.user.username in lawbook.config.developers:
        return disabled

    if request.user.username in lawbook.config.blog_writers:
        return disabled

    if request.user.username in lawbook.config.bio_writers:
        return disabled

    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        return disabled

# don't track in local development environment
if settings.DEBUG:
    return disabled

# don't track in staging
if lawbook.config.hostname.startswith('staging'):
    return disabled

if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated:
    username = request.user.username
else:
    username = None

context = {
    "google_analytics_key": settings.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_KEY,
    "username": username
}

return {
    'google_analytics': render_to_string("google_analytics.html", context) 
}
```

All I need to do is set a tag that does this on every page. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how good of an idea is to share your keys publicly but, here is the solution on django's part for what you ask.

```
def google_analytics_context_processor(request):
    # rest of your code
    return {'google_analytics': render_to_string("google_analytics.html", context)}
```

and then in your settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...,
                'dot.path.to.google_analytics_context_processor',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and then in your function views (class based views takes care of it automatically) you use

```
from django.template.context import RequestContext
def view(request):
    custom_context = {'custom': 'context'}
    context = RequestContext(request, custom_context)
    # now where-ever you want, you use this context 
    # and your context from the context_processors added 
    # in your new context
```